# Unable to create file in folder despite admin (and owner)

Tags: windows-10, permissions

I am trying to create a file in a folder, but windows wont let me do this (I have also tried using WSL and whatnot). Interestingly what did work was deleting it using `rm` in a console emulator but I now cannot create a new file. I am already the owner, and I have given my user full permissions:

[image]

How do I convince windows to let me create a file in that folder?

Here are the permissions for the particular file I am trying to modify. I can delete it, I can create it again, but I cannot write it.

Permissions:
[image]

Operations:
[image]

Comment: When you took ownership and reset permissions, did you make sure the "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects" and "Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object" checkboxes were checked?

Comment: I didnt, but I did everything again, and verified the permissions on the particular file I am trying to modify. I have added the results in my post.

Comment: That is a very secured folder for Windows use. You cannot create a folder there, even if you are Admin. More importantly, you should not use the folder for your own use.

Comment: Ill have to see then what other options I have, maybe using ZwCreateFile from kernel mode is an option... If I want to change a file on my computer this is not something I want to ask my OS, this is something it just has to do :)

Comment: Perhaps use another folder (not Program Files) for keeping files and information. That practice was common in Windows XP but died after that.

Comment: I am replacing a binary module of an existing application to make it easier debuggable, so thats not really an option :(. I assume this is some DRM non-sense, but that is even more incentive to work around it!

Comment: Well your pictures show permissions on a file, but your question is about folders. Your pictures are irrelevant to your question.

Comment: I want to create a file in a folder (as noted in the title), I have included pictures of the permissions on the folder I want to create the file in and of the file I want to write to, what would be relevant then?

Comment: You show permissions for libcef.dll ONLY.

Comment: The first image is of the windows app folder, the second screenshot is of the libcef.dll which I want to modify.

Comment: Type `cacls | clip` and paste the results.

Comment: I will try to keep this question updated. But for now I found the same app without windows store scam protection. Surprisingly it has the same widevine L3 quality level even though it does not benefit from the scandalous OS protection. I am going to perform reverse engineering on that application :)